# How to look up 64-bit module's function table when it's mapped in memory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, 64-bit, portable-executable

My goal is to understand [stack unwinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ydc79k6.aspx) in 64-bit PE32+ executable format in Windows, or how the following API can calculate addresses of a function prologue, body, epilogue, etc.:

```
CONTEXT context = {0};
RtlCaptureContext(&context);

DWORD64 ImgBase = 0;
RUNTIME_FUNCTION* pRTFn = RtlLookupFunctionEntry(context.Rip, &ImgBase, NULL);
_tprintf(L"Prologue=0x%p\n", (void*)(ImgBase + pRTFn->BeginAddress));
```

I know that the [information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssa62fwe.aspx) on the offsets of all *non-leaf* functions used by the linker [is included](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2010/05/12/x64-manual-stack-reconstruction-and-stack-walking/) in the PE32+ header in the exceptions directory. So I tried to write my own function to parse it. I got to this point where I got stumped:

```
//INFO -- must be compiled as x64 only!

void GetFunctionTable(BYTE* lpBaseAddress, size_t szImageSz)
{
    if(lpBaseAddress)
    {
        if(szImageSz > sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER))
        {
            IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pDOSHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)lpBaseAddress;
            if(pDOSHeader->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
            {
                IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pNtHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((BYTE*)pDOSHeader + pDOSHeader->e_lfanew);

                PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY pDataDirectories = NULL;
                if(pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC)
                {
                    //64-bit image only
                    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64* pHdr64 = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64*)pNtHeader;
                    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64* pIOH64 = &pHdr64->OptionalHeader;
                    pDataDirectories = pIOH64->DataDirectory;

                    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY* pExceptDir = &pDataDirectories[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION];
                    if(pExceptDir->VirtualAddress &&
                        pExceptDir->Size)
                    {
                        IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY* pRFs = (IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY*)
                            GetPtrFromRVA64(pExceptDir->VirtualAddress, pNtHeader, lpBaseAddress);

                        //'pRFs' = should point to an array of RUNTIME_FUNCTION structs
                        //         but in my case it points to an empty region of memory with all zeros.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the following helper functions:

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER GetEnclosingSectionHeader64(DWORD_PTR rva, PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 pNTHeader)
{
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pNTHeader);
    unsigned int i;

    for ( i=0; i < pNTHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++, section++ )
    {
        if ( (rva >= section->VirtualAddress) && 
                (rva < (section->VirtualAddress + section->Misc.VirtualSize)))
            return section;
    }

    return 0;
}

LPVOID GetPtrFromRVA64(DWORD rva, const void* pNTHeader, const void* imageBase)
{
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSectionHdr;
    INT_PTR delta;

    pSectionHdr = GetEnclosingSectionHeader64( rva, (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)pNTHeader );
    if ( !pSectionHdr )
        return 0;

    delta = (INT_PTR)(pSectionHdr->VirtualAddress - pSectionHdr->PointerToRawData);
    return (PVOID) ( (BYTE*)imageBase + rva - delta );
}
```

So I'm testing it on the self executable:

```
HMODULE hMod = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
MODULEINFO mi = {0};
if(::GetModuleInformation(::GetCurrentProcess(), hMod, &mi, sizeof(mi)))
{
    GetFunctionTable((BYTE*)hMod, mi.SizeOfImage);
}
```

But the problem is that inside my `GetFunctionTable` when I try to look up the function table mapped in memory in the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION` directory, I'm getting a pointer (i.e. `IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY*`) to an empty region of memory. I must be not translating the rva address correctly.

So anyone who knows how PE32+ header is mapped in memory, can please show what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: you already have `RVA` of exception. you not need convert it to offset. `IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY* pRFs = (IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY*)
                            GetPtrFromRVA64(pExceptDir->VirtualAddress, pNtHeader, lpBaseAddress);` this line is error. must be `IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY* pRFs = (IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY*)(lpBaseAddress+pExceptDir->VirtualAddress);`

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks. I tried it as well. But it points me in the wrong memory location as well. For some reason it is `0x1800` bytes short of what the actual function table is (I take it from the return pointer from `RtlLookupFunctionEntry` when I scroll up to its top.) So I'm not sure where that error in  `0x1800` bytes comes from?

Comment: no, with `IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY* pRFs = (IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY*)(lpBaseAddress+pExceptDir->VirtualAddress);` we get correct address

Comment: some example code of unwind - https://pastebin.com/5wBDstpG

Comment: @RbMm: Again, in my tests, the `lpBaseAddress+pExceptDir->VirtualAddress` part points to a correct function table **only** in a release build of this test console project. If I have the same standard console project built for `debug` it points to an empty area of memory. My guess is that the debug build uses `RtlAddFunctionTable()` or `RtlAddGrowableFunctionTable()` to add dynamic/JIT functions which re-allocates the function table. (Just a guess.) As for the code you posted, it works because you're using `RtlLookupFunctionEntry()` that does what I'm trying to emulate here.

Comment: I was able to find `RtlLookupFunctionTable()` function that is imported from `ntdll.dll` but 1. it's undocumented, and 2. I don't really know which parameters to call it with. Otherwise it may be doing exactly what I'm asking here.

Comment: From the research that I've done so far, it looks like what Microsoft was trying to do with the function table in x64 was to [cache it internally](http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=8&a=2&p=20). Thus the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION` section in PE32+ has just a static starter info, which may be later relocated if new JIT function definitions are added later.

Comment: no, you mistake. nothing relocated

Comment: @RbMm: Well, how is it my mistake? If I build the code I posted above as `debug` console project in VS2017 community and replace `GetPtrFromRVA64()` with `IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY* pRFs = (IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY*)(lpBaseAddress+pExceptDir->VirtualAddress);` [here's what I get](https://i.imgur.com/aggJR9t.png). `pRFs` points to an empty memory. Building a `release` [changes things](https://i.imgur.com/FK6Y3Bg.png).

Comment: you use different code. in one screenshot i view `pDataDirectory = pIOH32->DataDirectory` - no such line in your posted code and another screen. begin from use same code. post binary files

Comment: if you paste your test binary code, which incorrect calc this - i can say where mistake exactly

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks. You might be right. I could've been repeating the same mistake over and over. But I still don't see it. [Here's](https://mega.nz/#!SbBlRQZS!tMiypvCY8cl4zoBt5mauaC3780-2-HPAuPchRSeZIvo) the entire VS2017 solution that I'm using with two binary builds: release and debug.

Comment: simply open your debug build in peviewer. you can see that this data (inside `.pdata` section) is all zero. it initially zero in PE. (for example use http://www.andreybazhan.com/pe-internals.html)

Comment: so in code which access `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION` no errors. question why this data is all 0 filled in exe. may be some build or compile options.. but in my builds i never view this (however i for example never use incremental linking, etc. may be something affect this. also look your another pe in peviewer

Comment: no. it not all 0. begin from 1e800 rva not 0 data. think this is effect or incremental linking or some like this. play with link options - remove incremental, etc - move to release options one by one and found which exactly give this effect. anyway all 0 runtime function data formal also valid

Comment: @RbMm: OK, thanks. I should've checked it with PE viewer as well. Still, in despite of the `.pdata` section being empty, `RtlLookupFunctionEntry` function works and points to a filled function table. Also exceptions and stack unwinding work with that section being empty. There must be some undocumented flag in the PE32+ that we're not aware of. That's what I'm trying to get to the bottom of.

Comment: read my comments - section not empty. it begin with 0 but not empty. exist data.

Comment: @RbMm: I can see that. I pointed this out in one of the first comments that the actual data is 0x1800 bytes off from the `IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY* pRFs` pointer. Are those zeros an expected behavior though?

Comment: yes, why not ? and it not prevent `RtlLookupFunctionEntry` found valid entry. i guess this because incremental linking or may be some another build options. try change this for found exactly

Comment: @RbMm: OK, I'll play with it thanks. My curiosity at this point is this -- what would happen if I use `RtlAddFunctionTable()` to add more functions than the space left in the `.pdata` section? Did you have any experience with it?

Comment: `RtlAddFunctionTable` add table not to pe but in memory

Comment: @RbMm: So does it mean that there's more than one function table for a module?

Comment: every x64 *PE* have self function table. `RtlAddFunctionTable` let add additional tables for functions not located in any module (function table for dynamically generated code)

Comment: @RbMm: And do you know if there is a way to get a pointer to the head of that other "self function table"?

Comment: for what ? simply call `RtlLookupFunctionEntry` for get entry for *rip*

Comment: @RbMm: My problem with `RtlLookupFunctionEntry` is that it assumes current function and stack pointer, where in my case I might need to use a previous snapshot of the stack as a byte array is mem. But, like I said earlier, there's undocumented `RtlLookupFunctionTable` which may do the trick. I just need to re its input parameters. But that's beside the point ....... Hey, a little follow-up question. I'm assuming that there's no JIT'ing and thus `RtlAddFunctionTable` equivalent in the kernel space. Only the static `.pdata` section w/function table in the mapped images. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: `RtlLookupFunctionEntry` take `ControlPc` from you. no any "current function" stack pointer it al all not use